# Sending passwords over HTTPS: GET vs POST

Tags: rest, https

I'm creating a headless API that's going to drive an Angular front end. I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I should handle user authentication though.

Obviously the API should run over SSL, but the question that's coming up is how should I send the request that contains the user's password: over GET or POST. It's a RESTFUL API, so what I'm doing is retrieving information meaning it should get a GET request. But sending the password over get means it's part of the URI, right? I know even a GET request is encrypted over HTTPS, but is that still the correct way? Or is this a case to break from RESTFUL and have the data in the body or something (can a GET request have data in the body?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass the credentials in a request header, you will be fine with either a GET or POST request. You have the option of using the established Authorization header with your choice of authentication scheme, or you can create custom headers that are specific to your API.

When using header fields as a means of communicating credentials, you do not need to fear the credentials being written to the access log as headers are not included in that log. Using header fields also conforms to REST standards, and should actually be utilized to communicate any meta-data relevant to the resource request/response. Such meta-data can include, but is not limited to, information like: collection size, pagination details, or locations of related resources.

In summary, always use header fields as a means of authentication/authorization.

Comment: Interesting. I do use the `Authorization` header when passing my JWT, as expected, but I didn't realize it was standard to use it for initial authentication as well.

Answer (score 4):

mostly GET request will bind data in URL itself... so it is more redable than POST.. 
so if it is GET, **there is a possibility to alive HISTORY LOG**

Using `?user=myUsername&pass=MyPasswort` is exactly like using a GET based form and, while the Referer issue can be contained, the problems regarding logs and history remain.

Sending any kind of sensitive data over GET is dangerous, even if it is HTTPS. These data might end up in log files at the server and will be included in the Referer header in links to or includes from other sides. They will also be saved in the history of the browser so an attacker might try to guess and verify the original contents of the link with an attack against the history.

Comment: Is data saved by the browser even if it's a GET request over AJAX?

Comment: Sending sensitive data in the URL of a GET request is dangerous, yes, but only because the URL is logged on the server as you stated. However, sending sensitive data in a header field of a GET request is fine, so long as your are communicating over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a data body with a get request too but this isn't supported by all libraries I guess.

Better to use **POST** or request headers. Look at other APIs and how they are handling it.

But you could still use **GET** with basic authentication like here: http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/

Comment: So better to break REST in this case?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it doesn't matter too much. And i don't feel like you would break REST in this case. It is kind of a gray area :) but you could use basic authentification though

Comment: POST is not necessarily better. It will depend upon the action being taken against a resource.

Comment: Right. I think the way to go would be with basic auth or some sort of API token sent via http header